How can I set a code-behind property from a view model class?
I have my initial content page set up like this:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:PgViewModel"
             x:Class="LockAndKeyMaui.View.PasswdInfo"
             BackgroundColor="DarkGreen">

    <ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
        <MenuBarItem Text="Passwords">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Create New Database"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Select Password Database"
                            x:Name="mnuSelDb"
                            Command="{Binding GetDbsCommand}"/>
            <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit"
                            x:Name="mnuExit"
                            Clicked="mnuExit_Clicked"/>
        </MenuBarItem>
        <MenuBarItem Text="Groups"/>
    </ContentPage.MenuBarItems>

When I click on the MenuFlyoutItem that calls the GetDbsCommand from the view model class. I've tried this:
PasswdInfo.ViewPasswd = true;

but intellisense does not recognize ViewPasswd which is a public property in the code-behind of the content page.
So How do I bind a property from a C# code-behind file to a C# view model class file?

You shouldn't do this.  The VM shouldn't have any knowledge of the view it's bound to.  That's part of the MVVM pattern.  What you can do is bind the view property to a VM property, and then when you update the VM the View should also update

Thank you. That makes more sense. However, as you've probably detected i'm somewhat new to MVVM so how would I bind a public property that is located in code-behind to a property that is located in the view model class?

@BobGatto You don't, as Jason already pointed out. Please share more of the relevant code that you're dealing with, because currently it's not entirely clear what you're actually trying to achieve.

I think there is no problem with the view knowing their DataContext type, so you could cast your datacontext to your viewmodel class and so get their instance, something like this
public YourView_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = this.DataContext as YourViewModelType;
    ViewingPasswd = viewModel.PropertyDesired;
}

So, you could create a event in your viewmodel that fires when the command is executed and then subscribe to it from your view.
public YourView_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = this.DataContext as YourViewModelType;
    viewModel.CommandExecuted += (s, e) => {
        ViewingPasswd = viewModel.PropertyDesired
    };
}



how would I bind a public property that is located in code-behind to a
property that is located in the view model class?

If I understand correctly, do you want to get the value of the property from the View model class, right?
Then you can get the BindingContext of current page on file YourPage.xaml.cs
As a test, I added a button to the test page and tried to get the view model instance bind to current page by clicking this button with two ways.
You can refer to the following code:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public PgViewModel viewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new PgViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }


    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get information from viewModel

        //method 1
        bool value = viewModel.MyPasswdInfo.ViewPasswd;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("method1: " + value);

        //method 2
        PgViewModel model = this.BindingContext as PgViewModel;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("method2: " + model.MyPasswdInfo.ViewPasswd);

    }

    private void mnuExit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}

PgViewModel.cs
public class PgViewModel
{

    public ICommand GetDbsCommand { get; set; }

    public PasswdInfo MyPasswdInfo { get; set; }  


    public PgViewModel() {

        GetDbsCommand = new Command(DoSomething);

        MyPasswdInfo = new PasswdInfo();    

    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        MyPasswdInfo.ViewPasswd = true;
    }
 }

Note:
If we initialize the viewModel of current page as follows:
   public PgViewModel viewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new PgViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

Then, we can get the view model with the following method:
        bool value = viewModel.MyPasswdInfo.ViewPasswd;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("method1: " + value);

Of course, we can also use the second method：
        PgViewModel model = this.BindingContext as PgViewModel;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("method2: " + model.MyPasswdInfo.ViewPasswd);

